# tags/tag-name/media/recent endpoint returns null

Tags: instagram-api

I try to pull the posts from Instagram by hashtags.
So I use the tags endpoint to get recently posts about particular hashtags.
I use the url like this https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN.
But I get empty data in return, like:

```
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated
for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, 
"meta": {"code": 200},     "data": []}
```

I should get something back in the "data", because there are posts with that hashtag. Does tat means I use this api in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in Sandbox mode?

In Sandbox mode you will only see posts from you and your sandbox user, once you go live API will return posts from all users.

In Sandbox mode, You can search for hashtag that you have posted on Instagram, it will then have just that post in API response.

Read more about Sandbox mode and limitations here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: So, if you want to list all the media with specific tag from a user outside SandBox is not possible? I could get all media and then, filter the response, but in this way would require a lot of requests. Didn't find a endpoint for this case in their documentation, am I missing something?

Comment: yes, it is sandbox mode limitation, once you get your app approved with public_content scope and then go live, you will see all posts in response